# I'm trying to make a makefile that supports c++11

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, makefile, radix

It's a simple thing but I'm having trouble making a makefile.

It needs to support c++11 and I should be able to call it with ./radixsort in the linux terminal.

It just has two files, main.cpp and header.h

How would I write this up? So far every attempt doesn't work.

my last attempt:

```
radixsort: main.cpp header.h
     g++ -std=c++11 radixsort main.cpp header.h
```

Comment: please show a [mre] of what you've tried and the problems you encountered

Comment: I think there's some confusion.  A makefile is not a program.  A makefile is a description of how to _build_ a program.  You write the makefile to explain how your program should be built.  Then you run `make` to build it.  Then you run the program that was built, for example by typing `./radixsort`.  If running `make` doesn't do the right thing please edit your question to (a) use proper formatting, and (b) show the command you typed and the output / errors you got.

Comment: (1) Please use proper formatting in your question. Especially for a `Makefile` this does matter. (2) At the first glance you are missing the `-o`. Why don’t you start with running the command “manually” using the shell before experimenting with a `Makefile`?

Comment: However, the example you give is wrong because the compiler can't be invoked with just the name of the program to be built: you have to use the `-o` option to tell the compiler what name to use for the output.  Also you shouldn't put header files on the compile command line: they are added via `#include` in the source.  It should be `g++ -std=c++11 -o radixsort main.cpp`